# Command+Click does not work in Google Scholar + Firefox

Tags: firefox, google

For example, see this page:
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=cancer&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=

When I do <kbd>command</kbd>+click on the article titles, Firefox does neither open a link nor open a tab. In any other browsers, it works well. When I do right click and manually choose "Open Link in New Tab", it works well.

Is this only my problem, potentially a problem of one of my extensions?

Firefox 21.0, OS X Mountain Lion

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a problem restricted to your computer:

- Other Mac users (including me) have experienced similar problems with *scholar.google.com* and other websites when using [Firefox 19.0.2](https://github.com/SU-SWS/open_framework/issues/106) and [version 20.0](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/issues/14), or, in my case, with the same setup as yours (OS X 10.8.3 and Firefox 21).
- Windows users have also reported this issue, for example [here](https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa/issues/587) and [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4535).

I don't think it is not a problem caused by extensions, either. The problem seems rather related to how Firefox deals with some [CSS code](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7968) and [Javascript plugins](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7118).

**The extension [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) can be used as a workaround** at the cost of reducing functionality, because it blocks, among other things, JavaScript.

After installing NoScript *scholar.google.com* behaved as expected when I <kbd>⌘</kbd>-clicked the links. NoScript displays a yellow bar at the bottom when active:

[image]

**Important:** You will need to exclude *google.com* from the whitelist for this to work. This will also block Javascript and other plugins on *www.google.com*, so you may wish to whitelist it:

[image]